# Matplotlib: different font type rendering in axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-face, axis-labels

Using the code below I get a label that with two different font types.  'Surface Area' is in sans-serif, while the Angstrom and the superscript are serif.  Is there anyway I can make the entire y-label sans-serif?

Thanks in advance!

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import random

random.seed(20)
data = [random.random() for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(data)
ax.set_ylabel(r'Surface Area ($\AA^2$)', size =16)

plt.show()
```

[image: Surface Area]

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way in `matplotlib` version 1.3.0 and up, you can use `Latex` `\textup` and `\textbf`:

```
ax.set_ylabel('\textup{Surface Area} (\AA^2)', size =16)
```

see tutorials here: http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html, don't forget to enable `latex` by:

```
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

This should work for older versions as well as long as you have `Latex` installed. But if you want to stick to `matplotlib`'s `mathtext`, it can be done as well:

```
>>> matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset']='stixsans'
>>> for i in [1]:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data)
    ytx=ax.set_ylabel(r'Surface Area $(\AA^2)$', size =16)
```

Not every font will work with `mathtext`, `stixsans` is the one that will 'look like' `sans-serif`: http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial. Honestly, the difference is very small. I am pretty sure Angstrom is not in `stixsans` so to render it `mathtext` falls back to the default `Computer Modern` font.

[image]

Comment: any way to do this in v1.2.1?

Comment: I think it should, just I don't have v1.2.1 installed to really test it.

Comment: The Angstroms character (Å) is still Serif, however superscript is now in sans-serif

Comment: Yes, I know. That's what I was saying, `stixsans` doesn't provide angstroms. So when using `mathtext` to label y, the `angstroms` will still be the default font (`cm`). This is a situation you will need all the flexibility `Latex` can provide.